# Which matrices property should I use to prove that?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

> For any real number $\Theta$, we say $$R(\Theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
>  \cos\Theta  &-\sin\Theta \\ \sin\Theta & \cos\Theta \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Show that $(R(\Theta))^n= R(n\Theta)$ for any $\Theta \in
>  \mathbb{R}$ and for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$

I know it makes sense; I just don't know which linear property to use to prove it in a more generic way.

Hmm, I'm even more confused now. I tried $(R(\Theta))^3$, so I multiplied
$$(R(\Theta))^3=\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos2\Theta  &-\sin2\Theta \\ \sin2\Theta & \cos2\Theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\Theta  &-\sin\Theta \\ \sin\Theta & \cos\Theta \end{bmatrix}$$

but I did not end up with the expected

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos3\Theta  &-\sin3\Theta \\ \sin3\Theta & \cos3\Theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: i don't think so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may Try by induction on $n$. Then use the formulas: 
$$ \cos(a+b)= \cos(a) \cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$$ and  $$ \sin(a+b)= \cos(a) \sin(b) + \sin(a)\cos(b)$$
Noting that  $ (n+1) \theta =  n \theta +  \theta $.

Comment: I'm still very confused :S

Comment: for  $n=1$ , the result clearly holds. Now suppose the result holds for  $n$ ( i.e. $(R(\Theta))^n= R(n\Theta)$  ), and required to show it holds for  $n+1$. 
 we have  $$R( \Theta)^{n+1}=R( \Theta)^{n}*R( \Theta)= R( n\Theta)*R( \Theta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos n\Theta  &-\sin n\Theta \\ \sin n\Theta & \cos n\Theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\Theta  &-\sin\Theta \\ \sin\Theta & \cos\Theta \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos n\Theta \cos \Theta- \sin n\Theta \sin\Theta  & ...  \\ ... & ... \end{bmatrix}$$ = \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos (n\Theta + \Theta)  &... \\ ... & ...\end{bmatrix}

Comment: $$= \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos (n+1)\Theta   &... \\ ... & ...\end{bmatrix}  = (R((n+1)\Theta)) $$. I leave for you to fill in the place of the dots. Hope this made the idea clear.

Comment: got it, thank you, still a long way to go before it becomes intuitive but at least i got through this problem with your help.

Answer (score 6):

Prove a 'harder' theorem first:

$$ R(\Theta) R(\Phi) = R(\Theta + \Phi) $$

Answer (score 4):

Without spoiling the answer, try to regard the matrix $R$ not as a function $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$, but as a function $\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$.

There are plenty of ways to prove the general statement but I consider the complex variant a nice demonstration of the surprising efficiency of complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix $R(\theta)$ is a rotation matrix by $\theta$. $R(\theta)^n$ is the repeated application, $n$ times, of this rotation, meaning you are rotation by a total angle of $\theta+ \theta+...\theta$(n times), i.e., by doing $R(\theta)^n$ you are rotatiog by a total of $n\theta$, which is equal to $R(n\theta)$.